# Bind outgoing traffic to eth0 instead of eth0:1

Tags: linux, interface, ifconfig

We added a second IP-Adress to a linux (debian) machine to implement a second SSL-certificate to a new Apache vhost.

Our `ifconfig` now looks like this:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:0c:29:1b:ab:6c
          inet Adresse:999.999.999.39  Bcast:999.999.999.63  Maske:255.255.255.192
          inet6-Adresse: (...)/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX packets:219336884 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:223169420 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000
          RX bytes:1971307659 (1.8 GiB)  TX bytes:713489565 (680.4 MiB)

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse (...)
          inet Adresse:999.999.999.40  Bcast:999.999.999.63  Maske:255.255.255.192
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
```

Problem: All outgoing traffic (MySQL connections to external DB-server, outgoing SMTP connections from postfix) now seems to leave through eth0:1, hence the second (new) IP 999.999.999.40.

How can we force all outgoing traffic to leave through eth0, IP-adress 999.999.999.39?

Output of route:

```
[n1 ~ #] route
Kernel-IP-Routentabelle
Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
localnet        *               255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth0
10.10.10.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
default         gateway4.XXX    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         gateway4.XXX    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

**Found solution:**

Thanks for your hints, `ip route` was the way to go, now it works as desired.

```
ip rule add from 999.999.999.39 table t1
ip rule add from 999.999.999.40 table t2
ip route del default via 999.999.999.1
ip route add default 999.999.999.1 dev eth0 table t1
ip route flush cache
```

Comment: Can you append the output of `ip route` please?

Comment: eth0:1 is not actually an interface (you're being kidded by ifconfig—stop using it for your own good).

Comment: Did i understand you right? You have one server with multiple IP´s. You have Apache with multiple Virtualhosts. It looks like, i have a similar problem. Can you look my case? If it is the same, it is recoverable the changes, that would be made by the your solution comands?
http://serverfault.com/questions/511793/how-configure-apache-virtual-hosts-to-different-ips-for-outgoing-connection

Answer (score 4):

I think you'll have to play with the [route](http://linux.die.net/man/8/route) command to tell the system how to route the packets.
Something like :

```
route add -net APACHE_VHOST_IP netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth0:1
```

to force the packet in destination of APACHE_VHOST_IP to use the eth0:1 interface.

And

```
route add -net MYSQL_SERVER_IP netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth0
```

to force the packet in destination of MYSQL_SERVER_IP to use the eth0 interface.

Comment: This would make it nescessary to define all target-IPs, wouldn't it? I would like to force ALL outgoing traffic to eth0. eth0:1 actually only needs to listen

Comment: then define the default route to eth0

Comment: If you want listening on eth0:1 and sending the outgoing packets for incoming connections on eth0:1 to eth0, this is not possible. The IP protocol just doesn't work like that, the remote end would not recognize the packets.

Comment: Thank you for your help, see solution I added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `/etc/sysconfig/network`

```
GATEWAYDEV=eth0
```

Forces `default gateway` to `eth0` interface