# Remote MySQL connection on a https site php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have recently installed a SSL certificate on my website.

This has caused some issues which I was not expecting at all.

The issue that I have right now is that I cannot connect to the MySQL database!

My connection file is like this:

```
<?php
$db_conx = mysqli_connect("Mydomain.com", "mystore", "Mypassword", "mystore");
// Evaluate the connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
} else {
echo "";
}
?>
```

The code above was working perfectly fine before I installed the SSL but it has stopped connecting to the MySQL database since I installed the SSL.

if I change the

```
$db_conx = mysqli_connect("Mydomain.com", "mystore", "Mypassword", "mystore");
```

to

```
$db_conx = mysqli_connect("localhost", "mystore", "Mypassword", "mystore");
```

It starts working again but I need to use the domain name same as before as I will need it to connect to a remote MySQL database.

Once again, this was working just fine before I installed the SSL.

Could someone please advise on this and what needs to be done to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: SSL on the website shouldn't have any effect on the connection from the webserver to the database. Did you install SSL on the database server?

Comment: Did you change firewall configuration when you enabled SSL?

Comment: @Barmar, I don't think so. I asked my hosting company to install the SSL for me and they did it. I don't see any changes to the mysql either!

Comment: They must have changed something else. The webserver isn't even involved in the database connection. I suggest you talk to them.

Comment: possibple duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531835/bind-outgoing-traffic-to-eth0-instead-of-eth01

Answer (score 1):

try the connection with port

```
$db_conx = mysqli_connect("Mydomain.com:3306", "mystore", "Mypassword", "mystore");
```

Comment: with that, I get this error: `Unknown MySQL server host 'Mydomain.com:3306' (25)`. I did change Mydomain.com to my own domain by the way.

Comment: channge your domain name with server public ip

Answer (score 0):

Your hosting company might have changed/added IP address(es) to your machine, as traditionally certificates demanded their own IP address. Usually a hosting company would just add an extra IP address to your web server machine, on top of the IP address you already had.

Now if your PHP script uses the new IP address to connect to the MySQL server, your MySQL server might not recognize the new IP, and reject the connection.

Ask your hosting company to either set the former IP address as the one that PHP uses to connect to MySQL. Or ask them to set a route to the MySQL server via the former IP.

Or you can just check if you have enough privileges to change the IP address that the MySQL server grants access to.

Comment: read this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531835/bind-outgoing-traffic-to-eth0-instead-of-eth01 for the 'route' suggestion.